# Sonarqube in azure devops is not analyzing the .cs files

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, sonarqube

I am implementing a pipeline to analyze a repository that is in .NET, for the moment the analysis is successful but it is not analyzing the complete .cs files

```
name: $(Build.DefinitionName)_${{ replace(replace(variables['Build.SourceBranch'],'refs/heads/',''),'/','-')}}_$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)
    
variables:
- group: 'mygroup'
- name: agent
  value: devops
    
trigger: none
    
resources:
  containers:
  - container: devops
    image: myimage

stages:
  - stage: stage_environment
    pool: ${{ variables.agent }}
    displayName: Create environment
    jobs:
    - job: job_build
      displayName: Build Process
      container: devops
      steps:
      - checkout: self
        fetchDepth: 1

      - task: SonarQubePrepare@5.15.0
        inputs:
          SonarQube: 'azure-sonar'
          scannerMode: 'CLI'
          configMode: 'manual'
          cliProjectKey: 'prynet'
          cliProjectName: 'prynet'
          cliSources: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/config/'  # root of the project


      - task: UseDotNet@2
        inputs:
          command: 'build'
          
      - script: java -version
      - script: dotnet nuget --version
      
      - task: SonarQubeAnalyze@5.15.0

      - task: SonarQubePublish@5
        inputs:
          pollingTimeoutSec: '300'
```

Result:

```
2023-08-17T19:05:38.1268285Z ##[section]Starting: SonarQubeAnalyze
2023-08-17T19:05:38.1272203Z ==============================================================================
2023-08-17T19:05:38.1272324Z Task         : Run Code Analysis
2023-08-17T19:05:38.1272403Z Description  : Run scanner and upload the results to the SonarQube server.
2023-08-17T19:05:38.1272497Z Version      : 5.15.0
2023-08-17T19:05:38.1272554Z Author       : sonarsource
2023-08-17T19:05:38.1272614Z Help         : Version: 5.15.0. This task is not needed for Maven and Gradle projects since the scanner should be run as part of the build.

[More Information](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/install-configure-scanner-tfs-ts.html)
2023-08-17T19:05:38.1272848Z ==============================================================================
2023-08-17T19:05:38.4751876Z [command]/__w/_tasks/SonarQubeAnalyze_9589-4b15-8491-8164aeb38055/5.15.0/sonar-scanner/bin/sonar-scanner
2023-08-17T19:05:38.5614358Z INFO: Scanner configuration file: /__w/_tasks/SonarQubeAnalyze_9589-4b15-8491-8164aeb38055/5.15.0/sonar-scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
2023-08-17T19:05:38.5615493Z INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
2023-08-17T19:05:38.5822037Z INFO: SonarScanner 4.8.0.2856
2023-08-17T19:05:38.5822688Z INFO: Java 11.0.20 Ubuntu (64-bit)
2023-08-17T19:05:38.5823006Z INFO: Linux xxxxxxxxxxx amd64
2023-08-17T19:05:38.8251791Z INFO: User cache: /home/ec2-xxxxxxxxx/.sonar/cache
2023-08-17T19:05:39.1949427Z INFO: Analyzing on SonarQube server 6.7.5
2023-08-17T19:05:39.1950442Z INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "US-ASCII" (analysis is platform dependent)
2023-08-17T19:05:39.3827293Z INFO: Publish mode
2023-08-17T19:05:39.4884620Z INFO: Load global settings
2023-08-17T19:05:39.5407085Z INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=53ms
2023-08-17T19:05:39.5482441Z INFO: Server id: E7CCD9D6-AWUl_N6sMUMELsCFNm8K
2023-08-17T19:05:39.5548787Z INFO: User cache: /home/xxxxxxx/.sonar/cache
2023-08-17T19:05:39.7306581Z INFO: Load plugins index
2023-08-17T19:05:39.7661803Z INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=35ms
2023-08-17T19:05:39.7670130Z INFO: Download sonar-flex-plugin-2.3.jar
2023-08-17T19:05:39.7947177Z INFO: Download sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.8.0.1574.jar
2023-08-17T19:05:39.8242032Z INFO: Download sonar-jacoco-plugin-1.0.1.143.jar
2023-08-17T19:05:39.8273144Z INFO: Download sonar-csharp-plugin-6.5.0.3766.jar
2023-08-17T19:05:39.8546605Z INFO: Download sonar-javascript-plugin-5.1.1.7506.jar
2023-08-17T19:05:39.9264427Z INFO: Download sonar-java-plugin-5.13.0.18197.jar
2023-08-17T19:05:40.0086588Z INFO: Download sonar-php-plugin-2.11.0.2485.jar
2023-08-17T19:05:40.0404281Z INFO: Download sonar-python-plugin-1.8.0.1496.jar
2023-08-17T19:05:40.0818679Z INFO: Download sonar-typescript-plugin-1.9.0.3766.jar
2023-08-17T19:05:40.1058981Z INFO: Download sonar-xml-plugin-2.0.1.2020.jar
2023-08-17T19:05:40.1303159Z INFO: Download sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.8.0.1168.jar
2023-08-17T19:05:40.5513647Z INFO: Process project properties
2023-08-17T19:05:40.5738080Z INFO: Load project repositories
2023-08-17T19:05:40.6339122Z INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=60ms
2023-08-17T19:05:40.7124410Z INFO: Load quality profiles
2023-08-17T19:05:40.7473015Z INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=35ms
2023-08-17T19:05:40.7541965Z INFO: Load active rules
2023-08-17T19:05:41.0864730Z INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=332ms
2023-08-17T19:05:41.0880059Z INFO: Load metrics repository
2023-08-17T19:05:41.1135009Z INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=25ms
2023-08-17T19:05:41.1347465Z INFO: Project key: prynet
2023-08-17T19:05:41.1353687Z INFO: -------------  Scan prynet
2023-08-17T19:05:41.2324142Z INFO: Load server rules
2023-08-17T19:05:41.2675314Z INFO: Load server rules (done) | time=35ms
2023-08-17T19:05:41.3247704Z INFO: Base dir: /__w/165/s
2023-08-17T19:05:41.3248472Z INFO: Working dir: /__w/165/s/.scannerwork
2023-08-17T19:05:41.3255075Z INFO: Source paths: config
2023-08-17T19:05:41.3255716Z INFO: Source encoding: US-ASCII, default locale: en_US
2023-08-17T19:05:41.3628044Z INFO: Index files
2023-08-17T19:05:41.4280317Z INFO: 158 files indexed
2023-08-17T19:05:41.4288337Z INFO: Quality profile for cs: Sonar way
2023-08-17T19:05:41.4288721Z INFO: Quality profile for xml: Sonar way
2023-08-17T19:05:41.4288994Z INFO: Excluded sources for coverage: 
2023-08-17T19:05:41.4289265Z INFO:   **/domain/**/*
2023-08-17T19:05:41.4289524Z INFO:   **/distribution/**/*
2023-08-17T19:05:41.9358090Z WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
2023-08-17T19:05:41.9359856Z WARNING: Illegal reflective access by net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/home/ec2-user_azpcontainer/.sonar/cache/5xxeccc325307/sonar-javascript-plugin-5.1.1.7506.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
2023-08-17T19:05:41.9360631Z WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
2023-08-17T19:05:41.9361280Z WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
2023-08-17T19:05:41.9361733Z WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2023-08-17T19:05:42.1872180Z INFO: Sensor C# [csharp]
2023-08-17T19:05:42.1908612Z INFO: Sensor C# [csharp] (done) | time=4ms
2023-08-17T19:05:42.1909015Z INFO: Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java]
2023-08-17T19:05:42.1936741Z INFO: 12 source files to be analyzed
2023-08-17T19:05:42.4501684Z INFO: Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java] (done) | time=259ms
2023-08-17T19:05:42.4504799Z INFO: 12/12 source files have been analyzed
2023-08-17T19:05:42.4506868Z INFO: Sensor XML Sensor [xml]
2023-08-17T19:05:42.4532017Z INFO: 13 source files to be analyzed
2023-08-17T19:05:42.7004547Z INFO: Sensor XML Sensor [xml] (done) | time=249ms
2023-08-17T19:05:42.7005086Z INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
2023-08-17T19:05:42.7007762Z INFO: 13/13 source files have been analyzed
2023-08-17T19:05:42.7071392Z INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=6ms
2023-08-17T19:05:42.7071658Z INFO: Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php]
2023-08-17T19:05:42.7107564Z INFO: Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php] (done) | time=3ms
2023-08-17T19:05:42.7107991Z INFO: Sensor C# Tests Coverage Report Import [csharp]
2023-08-17T19:05:42.7108298Z INFO: Sensor C# Tests Coverage Report Import [csharp] (done) | time=1ms
2023-08-17T19:05:42.7108668Z INFO: Sensor [Deprecated] C# Integration Tests Coverage Report Import [csharp]
2023-08-17T19:05:42.7109010Z INFO: Sensor [Deprecated] C# Integration Tests Coverage Report Import [csharp] (done) | time=0ms
2023-08-17T19:05:42.7109339Z INFO: Sensor C# Unit Test Results Import [csharp]
2023-08-17T19:05:42.7109854Z INFO: Sensor C# Unit Test Results Import [csharp] (done) | time=0ms
2023-08-17T19:05:42.7110166Z INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
2023-08-17T19:05:42.7360978Z INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=25ms
2023-08-17T19:05:42.7361495Z INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer
2023-08-17T19:05:42.7361807Z INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=0ms
2023-08-17T19:05:42.7516804Z INFO: SCM provider for this project is: git
2023-08-17T19:05:42.7524188Z INFO: 21 files to be analyzed
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8191109Z WARN: Shallow clone detected, no blame information will be provided. You can convert to non-shallow with 'git fetch --unshallow'.
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8215346Z INFO: 0/21 files analyzed
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8217211Z WARN: Missing blame information for the following files:
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8217732Z WARN:   * config/SI.TPMOHO.ORDERS.XLSX.TXT/ConfigurationData.cs
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8218192Z WARN:   * config/SI.TPMOHO.ORDERS.XLSX.TXT/ExcelExit.Designer.cs
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8218601Z WARN:   * config/SI.TPMOHO.ORDERS.XLSX.TXT/ExcelExit.cs
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8219010Z WARN:   * config/SI.TPMOHO.ORDERS.XLSX.TXT/ExcelExit.xsd
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8219905Z WARN:   * config/SI.TPMOHO.ORDERS.XLSX.TXT/MailManager.cs
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8220285Z WARN:   * config/SI.TPMOHO.ORDERS.XLSX.TXT/Map.cs
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8220821Z WARN:   * config/SI.TPMOHO.ORDERS.XLSX.TXT/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8221254Z WARN:   * config/SI.TPMOHO.ORDERS.XLSX.TXT/ref/Configurations.xml
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8221713Z WARN:   * config/SI.TPMOHO.ORDERS.XLSX.TXT/ref/PGAConfig.xml
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8222168Z WARN:   * config/SI.TPMOHO.ORDERS.XLSX.TXT/bin/Debug/ref/Configurations.xml
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8222642Z WARN:   * config/SI.TPMOHO.ORDERS.XLSX.TXT/bin/Debug/ref/PGAConfig.xml
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8223103Z WARN:   * config/SI.TPMOHO.ORDERS.XLSX.TXT/bin/Release/ref/Configurations.xml
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8223579Z WARN:   * config/SI.TPMOHO.ORDERS.XLSX.TXT/bin/Release/ref/PGAConfig.xml
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8224050Z WARN:   * config/TEST/Program.cs
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8224356Z WARN:   * config/TEST/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8224721Z WARN:   * config/TEST/bin/Debug/crv.IPS.SIT.ORM.xml
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8225082Z WARN:   * config/TEST/bin/Debug/ref/Configurations.xml
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8225456Z WARN:   * config/TEST/bin/Debug/ref/PGAConfig.xml
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8225819Z WARN:   * config/TEST/bin/Release/crv.IPS.SIT.ORM.xml
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8226175Z WARN:   * config/TEST/bin/Release/ref/Configurations.xml
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8226537Z WARN:   * config/TEST/bin/Release/ref/PGAConfig.xml
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8226878Z WARN: This may lead to missing/broken features in SonarQube
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8227187Z INFO: Calculating CPD for 0 files
2023-08-17T19:05:42.8244823Z INFO: CPD calculation finished
2023-08-17T19:05:42.9687769Z INFO: Analysis report generated in 137ms, dir size=346 KB
2023-08-17T19:05:43.0172080Z INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 48ms, zip size=77 KB
2023-08-17T19:05:43.0561265Z INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 39ms
2023-08-17T19:05:43.0572289Z INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://xxxxxxxxx:9000/sonar/dashboard/index/prynet
2023-08-17T19:05:43.0572900Z INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
2023-08-17T19:05:43.0573544Z INFO: More about the report processing at http://xxxxxxxxx:9000/sonar/api/ce/task?id=AYoE46dzrGTyIW5modwg
2023-08-17T19:05:43.0695434Z INFO: Task total time: 2.782 s
2023-08-17T19:05:43.1526075Z INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023-08-17T19:05:43.1526574Z INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
2023-08-17T19:05:43.1526920Z INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023-08-17T19:05:43.1527112Z INFO: Total time: 4.604s
2023-08-17T19:05:43.1945932Z INFO: Final Memory: 12M/60M
2023-08-17T19:05:43.1946679Z INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023-08-17T19:05:43.2636294Z ##[section]Finishing: SonarQubeAnalyze
```

This is the complete log, I already did the test locally and locally if it shows me the bugs and the .cs files.

In short, this log shows the complete SonarQube analysis process, from configuring and downloading plugins to running sensors to analyze source code and generating analysis reports that will be uploaded to the SonarQube server for viewing and follow-up.

Comment: Did you see the warning that tells you exactly what the problem is and how to fix it?